# Codename one - autocompletetextfield getitem selected

Tags: codenameone

I have two problems:

1) First, I want to add a map in `AutoCompleteTextField` exactlly in `DefaultListModel` and after I want to add the the listmodel in my `autocompletetextField`

2) How can I get the text when I select an element in the `AutoCompleteTextField`?

```
    Form hi = new Form("Auto Complete", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField("Short", "Shock", "Sholder", "Shrek0", "3asna", "niazra");
    ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
    //final DefaultListModel<Map<String,Object>> options = new DefaultListModel<>();
    final DefaultListModel<String> options = new DefaultListModel<>();

    AutoCompleteTextField an = new AutoCompleteTextField(options);
    hi.add(an);
    ac.addListListener(a -> {
        List<Object> ls = new List<>();
        System.out.println("i want to display the text selected");

    });
    hi.add(ac);
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you select an item in the suggestion box of an AutoCompleteTextField the text of this item is copied to the TextField part of the AutoCompleteTextfield, but this occur only after the ListEvent.

In order to have this behavior, prefer using a Selection Listener on the DefaultListModel:

```
    Form hi = new Form("ACTF", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    DefaultListModel<String> defList = new DefaultListModel<>("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange");
    AutoCompleteTextField tf1 = new AutoCompleteTextField(defList);

    defList.addSelectionListener((oldid, newid)-> Log.p(defList.getItemAt(newid)));

    hi.add(tf1);
    hi.show();
```

I don't know why, it occur two times after showing the form, but it works perfectly fine after.

**Edit:** If you want to display the text on screen, you must use something like this :

```
    Form hi = new Form("ACTF", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Label text = new Label("Selected text");

    DefaultListModel<String> defList = new DefaultListModel<>("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange");
    AutoCompleteTextField tf1 = new AutoCompleteTextField(defList);

    defList.addSelectionListener((oldid, newid)-> {
        text.setText(defList.getItemAt(newid));
        hi.revalidate();
    });
    hi.add(text);
    hi.add(tf1);
    hi.show();
```

**EDIT 2:** Example with a linked map:

```
    Form hi = new Form("ACTF", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Map testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    testMap.put("Red", "Roses are red");
    testMap.put("Green", "Grass is green");
    testMap.put("Blue", "Sky is blue");
    testMap.put("Orange", "Apricots are orange");

    Label text = new Label("Selected text");



    DefaultListModel<String> defList = new DefaultListModel<>(testMap.keySet());
    AutoCompleteTextField tf1 = new AutoCompleteTextField(defList);

    defList.addSelectionListener((oldid, newid)-> {
        text.setText((String) testMap.get(defList.getItemAt(newid)));
        hi.revalidate();
    });
    hi.add(text);
    hi.add(tf1);
    hi.show();
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the selected text ? On the device's screen ? Here my code send the text to the debug console, like System.out.println would. Check the edited version of the example.

Comment: thanks it work but i want now to add a map in a AutoComAutoCompleteTextField because when i select item i want to get id 
I do not know if you understood me
here is an example
final DefaultListModel<Map<String,Object>> options = new DefaultListModel<>();
        AutoCompleteTextField an = new AutoCompleteTextField(options);

Comment: You can't add a map to the default list model.  The list model uses an array which maps a zero-based index to a value.  If you want to track a string ID to an Object, you will need to keep a corresponding list of your keys with the same indices as the list model - or make the entry values into objects that also store the key that you are interested in.

Comment: please you can give me an example because the AutoCompleteTextField Does not support a map

Comment: Keep a map variable then in the action listener just do `map.get(autoComplete.getText())`